# How to show that LCM and GCD of any two elements of a set lies in the set?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

> Let $A := \{x : x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x$ divides $30 \}$

$A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30\}$

How can I show that for any two elements $(a, b) \in A$, there LCM and GCD also lies in $A$.
I have no idea where to begin

Comment: Did you check if the statement is true or not? The set contain only 8 elements.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's true @Krish

Comment: Do you want to see a proof for the general statement, i.e. for $A = \{x \mid x \text{ divides } n\}$? Because this special case could be checked by hand (well... with some work). For the general statement you have to look at the definition of LCM and GCD.

Answer (score 0):

The set $A$ is defined with a property, namely, its elements are precisely the divisors of $30$.

Are the LCM and the GCD of two divisors of $30$ a divisor of $30$?

Answer (score 0):

This is true *iff* $\mid A\mid=\tau (lcm(x:x\in A))$ where $\tau (n)$=Number of positive divisors of $n$

You can use this result which is more applicable for practical usefulness: $\mid A\mid=\tau ($maximum element of A$))$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? What is $A$ in your case?

Comment: Let $A$ be a *finite* set. Then $LCM$ or $GCD$ of any two element of $A$ is in $A$ *iff* the mentioned property

Comment: I'm sure this answer wont help him, otherwise he wouldn't ask such a specific question.

Comment: Then I am editing my answer. Is this helpful

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be a positive integer and define 
$D_n = \{ x \in \mathbb ZX^+ : x \mid n \}$ be the set of all divisors of $n$.

Let $u, v \in D_n$ and let $g = \gcd(u,v)$. Since $g \mid u$ and $u \mid n$, then $g \mid n$. Hence $\gcd(u,v) \in D_n$.

Since $u, v \in D_n$, then $u \mid n$ and $v \mid n$. So $\operatorname{lcm}(u,v) \mid n$. Hence $\operatorname{lcm}(u,v) \in D_n$.